# How can I check the type of an attribute based on the parent object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object like this

```js
interface Container {
 type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c',
 data: DataA | DataB | DataC
}
```

where `DataA, DataB, DataC` are other interfaces with similar attributes between one another.

I know I can write a type-check function like this

```js
function isDataA(data: DataA | DataB | DataC): data is DataA
```

But how can I write something like this?

```js
function isDataA(container: Container): container.data is DataA {
 return container.type === 'a';
}
```

I want to check the type of a child attribute, but using another attribute from the same object (at the same level, instead of a level deep)

Comment: Sounds like the container should be a union: `type Container = { type: 'a', data: DataA } | { type: 'b', data: DataB } | { type: 'c', data: DataC }`

Comment: I simplified for the question, but the container has a bunch of different fields other than those 2

Comment: Then you can use distributive conditional type to produce the union https://tsplay.dev/WG660m

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** typeguard function as in OP   [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QGgyGCGHAoXgwo4AAbMjhpLGakUHG4PEAcTweCITgw7P5EBIfdUQuKe0gLzewKCPrg0T8aedICi30UeGeSQSstMjbwVYgBireDowtxbY7Xb90JL4a3fSbOBPWjgXdNbo5KkKA-fjmHgVHEBevyTjsiCzvO4SLi8K5rokm4NreO57geR73i2j7nlwPDWDWEBAA)

```js
type DataType = Record<string, string> // dummy parent type for DataA, DataB, etc...

interface DataTypeA extends DataType {
  propertyA: string
}

interface DataTypeB extends DataType {
  propertyB: string
}

// using generics, Container now becomes typed to a certain data type
interface Container<T extends DataType> {
 type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c',
 data: T
}

// the typeguard function checks for object consistency
function isDataType<T extends DataType>(container: Container<T>): container is Container<T> {
 if (container.type === 'a' && "propertyA" in container.data) return true
 if (container.type === 'b' && "propertyB" in container.data) return true
 return false
}

const checkGoodA = isDataType<DataTypeA>({
  type: 'a',
  data: {propertyA: 'foo'}
})

console.log(checkGoodA) // true


const checkBadA = isDataType<DataTypeA>({
  type: 'b',
  data: {propertyA: 'foo'}
})

console.log(checkBadA) // false
```

**Solution 2:** use union type [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```js
// using generics, Container now becomes typed to a certain data type
interface BaseContainer<T extends DataType, K extends string> {
 type: K,
 data: T
}

type Container = BaseContainer<DataTypeA, 'a'> | BaseContainer<DataTypeB, 'b'>

const GoodA: Container = { // ok
  type: 'a',
  data: {propertyA: 'foo'}
}

const BadA: Container  = {   // error
  type: 'b',
  data: {propertyA: 'foo'}
}

const GoodB: Container = { // ok
  type: 'b',
  data: {propertyB: 'foo'}
}
```